# How to use Calendar Panel UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I tried to look for how to use the calendar panel in UWP, but without results.

Is there a point from which to start or rather a small example of how to populate it?

always thanks.

Comment: Only controls that are related to calendar are `CalendarView` and `CalendarDatePicker`. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you really want is [Calendar view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/calendar-view) or [Calendar date picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/calendar-date-picker) control. For samples you can just reference the two documents I linked or reference [CalendarViewPage](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/CalendarViewPage.xaml) inside the official sample.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the example in [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/Calendar)

It will tell you how to use it. And you can read [Contacts and calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/)

Comment: Suggested examples include the calendar, but not the calendar panel .. how can I use it?

Comment: @Res I don't know what is Calendar Panel? Can you give me an image?

Comment: @Res Do you see [Windows-universal-samples/CalendarViewPage.xaml ](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/CalendarViewPage.xaml )?